# Convert string from feedparser to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, feedparser

I'd like to convert the string obtained as follows into `datetime`:

```
d = feedparser.parse(xmlUrl)
t = datetime.strptime(d.feed.updated, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

note the `T` and `Z` letters in the mask. They can be missing and I'm not sure what else can be in this format and how to create the mask to cover all possibilities.

The problem here is that the mask sometimes match and sometimes not. Could the matching be done to always match?

Comment: Well, what do the input strings look like? You might have to either use several masks for all the possible input formats, or use [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and hope none of your inputs are formatted in a way that would confuse it.

Comment: @millimoose These are the input [strings](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/reference-feed-updated.html)

Comment: @millimoose I will try to use rather `feed.updated_parsed` which gives struct_time, but wonder what is the best practice here.

Comment: I meant the actual inputs from your data that cause the mask to fail, but I think `updated_parsed` is the right way to go here if the results it gives you are correct. (I.e. in the timezone you want them to be if the string doesn't specify one explicitly. Or if you don't really care about that for your use case.)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the parsed forms of the date fields: `feed.updated_parsed` contains a [`struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time) like the one returned by `time.gmtime()`.